# VHDL unintended behavior when connecting components

Tags: embedded, vhdl, fpga, spi

I have two components I'm trying to connect, one is an SPI Receiver and one is a CDC Unit. Receiver receives 24 bit RGB pixels from a RPI4 master and sends it to a FIFO Module. But since the SPI frequency is 50 MHz and I intend on using 200MHz domain inside, I designed a cdc unit to pass one and multi bit signals through. The problem occurs at the multi-bit crossing. Either the async fifo in the cdc unit-1 is not working correctly, according to a vivado simulation it does, or I wrote the testbench wrong and cannot determine the problem.

I simulated every component individually and they are working as intended but a testbench which connects the given two modules does not. It passes one bit signals succesfully but outputs "UUUUUU" for the 24-bit pixel data. I tried to adjust the control signals for the fifo but it was no good. I really don't know what the problem is... I will provide the source code for the receiver, cdc unit, and the testbench I wrote below, with the waveform of the last simulation.

SPI Receiver:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity spi_receiver is
    port(
        master_clk         : in  std_logic; -- Master Clock
        reset            : in  std_logic; -- Global Reset
        master_ready     : in  std_logic; -- Chip Select
        MOSI             : in  std_logic; -- MOSI line
        write_permission : in  std_logic; -- Signal indicating permission to write to FIFO Buffer
        receiver_out     : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0); -- 24-bit pixel data output
        pixel_valid      : out std_logic; -- Indicates a valid pixel is ready
        can_receive      : out std_logic  -- Indicates if the receiver can accept more data
    );
end entity;

architecture spi_receiver_arch of spi_receiver is
    type state_type is (IDLE, RECEIVING, DATA_READY);
    signal state        : state_type := IDLE;
    signal pixel_buffer : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal ptr          : integer range 0 to 23 := 0;
begin
    Data_Input: process(master_clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            state <= IDLE;
            pixel_buffer <= (others => '0');
            ptr <= 0;
            pixel_valid <= '0';
            can_receive <= '1'; -- Indicating that receiver is ready after reset
        elsif rising_edge(master_clk) then
            case state is
                when IDLE =>
                    if master_ready = '1' and write_permission = '1' then
                        state <= RECEIVING;
                        pixel_valid <= '0';
                        can_receive <= '0'; -- Not ready to receive during data capturing
                    else
                        can_receive <= '1'; -- Ready to receive when IDLE
                    end if;

                when RECEIVING =>
                    pixel_buffer(23 - ptr) <= MOSI;
                    if ptr < 23 then
                        ptr <= ptr + 1;
                        can_receive <= '0'; -- Continue receiving, not ready for new data
                    else
                        state <= DATA_READY;
                        ptr <= 0;
                    end if;

                when DATA_READY =>
                    receiver_out <= pixel_buffer;
                    pixel_valid <= '1';
                    if write_permission = '0' then
                        state <= IDLE;
                        can_receive <= '1'; -- Ready to receive when IDLE
                    else
                        state <= RECEIVING;
                        can_receive <= '0'; -- Continue receiving, not ready for new data
                    end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
end spi_receiver_arch;
```

CDC Unit-1:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use work.func_pkg.all;

entity CDC_Unit_1 is
    port(
        -- Clocks
        master_clk         : in std_logic;
        internal_clk       : in std_logic;

        -- Reset
        reset              : in std_logic;

        -- Signals from SPI Receiver (50 MHz domain)
        receiver_out       : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
        pixel_valid        : in std_logic;  -- Retained
        

        -- Signals to FIFO Buffer and Controller (200 MHz domain)
        receiver_out_cdc   : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
        pixel_valid_cdc    : out std_logic;  -- Retained
        cdc_write          : in std_logic;  -- New signal
        
        -- Signal from FIFO Buffer Controller (200 MHz domain)
        write_permission       : in std_logic;
        cdc_read               : in std_logic;  -- New signal for read enable 

        -- Signal to SPI Receiver and FIFO Buffer (50 MHz domain)
        write_permission_cdc   : out std_logic;
        
        -- CDC FIFO signals
        fifo_empty         : out std_logic;
        fifo_full          : out std_logic       
    );
end entity;

architecture Behavioral of CDC_Unit_1 is
    -- Instantiate Dual Clock FIFO for receiver_out
    component async_fifo is
        generic(
            DATA_WIDTH : natural := 24;
            FIFO_DEPTH : natural := 160
        );
        port(
            wr_clk     : in  std_logic;
            rd_clk     : in  std_logic;
            reset      : in  std_logic;
            data_in    : in  std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
            data_out   : out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
            wr_en      : in  std_logic;
            rd_en      : in  std_logic;
            fifo_full  : out std_logic;
            fifo_empty : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    -- Instantiate Dual Flip Flop Synchronizers
    component cdc_single_bit is
        port(
            clk_a      : in  std_logic;
            clk_b      : in  std_logic;
            signal_in  : in  std_logic;
            signal_out : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

begin
    -- Dual Clock FIFO for receiver_out data
    receiver_out_fifo: async_fifo
        generic map (
            DATA_WIDTH => 24,
            FIFO_DEPTH => 160
        )
        port map (
            wr_clk     => master_clk,
            rd_clk     => internal_clk,
            reset      => reset,
            data_in    => receiver_out,
            data_out   => receiver_out_cdc,
            wr_en      => cdc_write,      -- Changed to cdc_write
            rd_en      => cdc_read,        -- New signal for read enable
            fifo_empty  => fifo_empty,
            fifo_full => fifo_full
        );

    -- Synchronize pixel_valid signal from SPI Receiver to FIFO Buffer Controller
    sync_pixel_valid: cdc_single_bit
        port map (
            clk_a      => master_clk,
            clk_b      => internal_clk,
            signal_in  => pixel_valid,
            signal_out => pixel_valid_cdc
        );

    -- Synchronize write_permission signal from FIFO Buffer Controller to SPI Receiver and FIFO Buffer
    sync_write_permission: cdc_single_bit
        port map (
            clk_a      => internal_clk,
            clk_b      => master_clk,
            signal_in  => write_permission,
            signal_out => write_permission_cdc
        );

end Behavioral;
```

Testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity tb_spi_cdc is
end entity tb_spi_cdc;

architecture sim of tb_spi_cdc is
    -- Component Declarations
    component spi_receiver
        port(
            master_clk         : in  std_logic;
            reset              : in  std_logic;
            master_ready       : in  std_logic;
            MOSI               : in  std_logic;
            write_permission   : in  std_logic;
            receiver_out       : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
            pixel_valid        : out std_logic;
            can_receive        : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    component CDC_Unit_1
        port(
            master_clk         : in std_logic;
            internal_clk       : in std_logic;
            reset              : in std_logic;
            receiver_out       : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
            pixel_valid        : in std_logic;
            receiver_out_cdc   : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
            pixel_valid_cdc    : out std_logic;
            cdc_read           : in  std_logic;
            cdc_write          : in std_logic;
            write_permission   : in std_logic;
            write_permission_cdc : out std_logic;
            fifo_empty         : out std_logic;
            fifo_full          : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    component clk_wiz_0
        port(
            reset    : in  std_logic;
            clk_in1  : in  std_logic;
            clk_out1 : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    -- Signals for interconnecting components and testbench
    signal master_clk         : std_logic := '0';
    signal internal_clk       : std_logic;
    signal clk_wiz_reset      : std_logic := '0';
    signal reset              : std_logic := '1';
    signal master_ready       : std_logic := '0';
    signal MOSI               : std_logic := '0';
    signal write_permission   : std_logic := '1';
    signal receiver_out       : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
    signal pixel_valid        : std_logic;
    signal can_receive        : std_logic;
    signal receiver_out_cdc   : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
    signal pixel_valid_cdc    : std_logic;
    signal cdc_read_ctrl      : std_logic := '1';
    signal cdc_write_ctrl     : std_logic := '1';
    signal write_permission_cdc : std_logic;
    signal fifo_empty         : std_logic;
    signal fifo_full          : std_logic;

begin
    -- SPI Receiver Instance
    uut_spi_receiver: spi_receiver
        port map (
            master_clk => master_clk,
            reset => reset,
            master_ready => master_ready,
            MOSI => MOSI,
            write_permission => write_permission,
            receiver_out => receiver_out,
            pixel_valid => pixel_valid,
            can_receive => can_receive
        );

    -- CDC Unit-1 Instance
    uut_cdc_unit_1: CDC_Unit_1
        port map (
            master_clk => master_clk,
            internal_clk => internal_clk,
            reset => reset,
            receiver_out => receiver_out,
            pixel_valid => pixel_valid,
            receiver_out_cdc => receiver_out_cdc,
            pixel_valid_cdc => pixel_valid_cdc,
            write_permission => write_permission,
            write_permission_cdc => write_permission_cdc,
            fifo_empty => fifo_empty,
            fifo_full => fifo_full,
            cdc_read => cdc_read_ctrl,
            cdc_write => cdc_write_ctrl
        );

    -- Clock Wizard Instance
    clk_wizard: clk_wiz_0
        port map (
            reset => clk_wiz_reset,
            clk_in1 => master_clk,
            clk_out1 => internal_clk
        );

    -- Master Clock Process (50 MHz)
    master_clk_process: process
    begin
        while true loop
            master_clk <= not master_clk; 
            wait for 20 ns;  -- 50 MHz clock
        end loop;
    end process;

    -- Test Stimulus Process
    stimulus: process
        variable pixel_data : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := x"CCBBAA"; -- Test RGB pixel
    begin
        -- Initialize inputs
        reset <= '1';
        master_ready <= '0';
        MOSI <= '0';
        write_permission <= '1';
        clk_wiz_reset <= '0';
        cdc_read_ctrl <= '0';
        cdc_write_ctrl <= '1';
        wait for 100 ns; -- Wait for system initialization

        -- Apply reset
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 40 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Activate SPI Transfer
        master_ready <= '1';
        for i in 23 downto 0 loop
            MOSI <= pixel_data(i);
            wait for 40 ns; -- Two clock cycles for stability
        end loop;
        master_ready <= '0';
        cdc_read_ctrl <= '1';
        cdc_write_ctrl <= '0';
        wait for 200 ns;

        -- End of simulation
        wait; 
    end process;

end sim;
```

Waveform: [image: waveform of the last simulation]

Comment: Note the lack of an interesting internal_clk and what appears to be reset being held '1' most of the time which is the reset value for spi_receiver. You don't show state in your waveform and pixel_valid never goes to '1'. I'd suspect the clk_wizard requires the same reset polarity.  Without seeing source for clk_wiz_0 and CDC_Unit_1 you simply need to invert the testbench reset. There of course could be other issues unseen, lacking a [mcve].